# Modal closes if clicked inside and release mouse outside

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im having an issue with modal in React. The problem is Modal closes if I click inside content and move mouse and release outside. This shouldnt happen.

Currently it works fine because if I click outside content the modal closes, but if I click inside, the modal stays.

But dragging mouse click from inside to outside closes it...

https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-newton-fqe6b

Looking for help! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I do experience the behavior you're describing. Pretty weird, I was under the impression that `e.target` in this instance would always refer to the interior div if the click event was initiated on that element, but maybe that's not accurate.  I tried using `stopPropagation()`, but it doesn't work because the click event seems to completely ignore the element that the mousedown portion of the click was actually initiated on.

I made a [hacky workaround](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-pasteur-qi6id) that will save the initial target in the state for comparison with the `currentTarget` and achieve the effect you're looking for, but this definitely bears some looking in to.